# Python library to georeference raster image from x- and y- coordinate files?

Tags: python, maps

I have a multiband raster image of e.g. 2000 x 5000 pixels. The file was captured in a machine vision project.

In addition, I have two files with x- and y-coordinates for each pixel of the raster image. These result from an orthorectification process, so **the coordinates are not in a regularly spaced grid.** The coordinates are in a rectangular, local grid with a pixel size of less than one mm.

I am looking for a Python library/toolbox to apply those coordinate sets to the raster image, creating a georeferenced output raster image. Interpolation of data for empty pixels is needed but that could probably be done by myself. This is the same as the process in ENVI using GLTs for georeferencing, except this has to be in Python.

The coordinates are in a rectangular, local grid with a raster pixel size of less than one mm.

I have been looking into GDAL and Rasterio, but all I have found there are georeferencing algorithms using GCPs (Ground Control Points).